# Doctrine - querybuilder - how to make to results from "join" query were not alternately?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to table Stats and Stat_values. These tables are in relatioship many to one (A stat can have a lot of stat_value)

I created query via querybuilder:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(array('s', 'v'))
    ->from("CMailingDefaultBundle:Stat", "s")
    ->leftJoin("CMailingDefaultBundle:StatValue", "v")
    ->where("s.project = :project")
    ->andWhere("v.isCurrent = 1")
    ->setParameter("project", $project )
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

It works good, but I don't have result in this way (I make it simpler, because all structure of array is so big):

```
[0] => Stats.field1, Stats.field2, ..., Stat_values.field1, Stat_values, ...
[1] => Stats.field1, Stats.field2, ..., Stat_values.field1, Stat_values, ...
etc...
```

but I have:

```
[0] => Stats.field1, Stats.field2, ...
[1] => Stat_values.field1, Stat_values ...
etc...
```

It is "litle bit" annoying. I tried change `select` arguments to "s, v" - the results are the same.

Do you have any ideas how to make to datas was ordered in first way?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you're not requesting the relation, just a seperate entity?

Instead of:

```
->from("CMailingDefaultBundle:Stat", "s")
->leftJoin("CMailingDefaultBundle:StatValue", "v")
```

Try:

```
->from("CMailingDefaultBundle:Stat", "s")
->leftJoin("s.StatValue", "v")
```

Assuming the Stat entity has a relation called StatValue...

Answer (score 0):

You can use another hydration method.
Doctrine provides 5 hydration methods, as listed below:

```
/**
 * Hydrates an object graph. This is the default behavior.
 */
const HYDRATE_OBJECT = 1;

/**
 * Hydrates an array graph.
 */
const HYDRATE_ARRAY = 2;

/**
 * Hydrates a flat, rectangular result set with scalar values.
 */
const HYDRATE_SCALAR = 3;

/**
 * Hydrates a single scalar value.
 */
const HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR = 4;

/**
 * Very simple object hydrator (optimized for performance).
 */
const HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT = 5;
```

HYDRATE_SCALAR gives you what you are looking for.

So change the call of: `getResult();` to `getResult(3);` or a little nicer by using the actual constant name: `getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR)`